# Exiting gracefully when running an invalid command c++

Tags: c++, exception, boost, command-line

I'm using boost for running commandline commands from my application. I am using the following piece of code that I've encapsulated into a helper function:

```
tuple<string, int> Utility::RunCommand(const string& arguments) const
{
    string response;
    int exitCode;
    try
    {
        ipstream iStream;
        auto childProcess = child(arguments, std_out > iStream);
        string line;

        while (getline(iStream, line) && !line.empty())
        {
            response += line;
        }

        childProcess.wait();
        exitCode = childProcess.exit_code();
    }
    catch (...)
    {
        // log error
        throw;
    }

    return make_tuple(response, exitCode);
}
```

Now I have a command which only runs on machines with certain properties. This method returns the expected response and error code on those machines. On other machines, it throws an exception.

I've tried running the command manually on a machine where it's supposed to fail and it returns the following output:

```
POWERSHELL
PS C:\Users\xyz> dummy-cmd
dummy-cmd : The term 'dummy-cmd' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
At line:1 char:1
+ dummy-cmd
+ ~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (dummy-cmd:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException

COMMAND PROMPT
C:\Users\xyz>dummy-cmd
'dummy-cmd' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

How can I make it run such that it returns a non-zero error code rather than throwing an exception?

Comment: The problem is your executable does not exist. That is what Powershell is complaining about.

Comment: Are you compiling your code to get a `dummy-cmd.exe`?

Comment: @doron True, I'm aware of that part. I'm wondering if there's a way to call the command so it returns back an error code instead of throwing the exception?

Comment: @FredLarson No. dummy-cmd.exe exists on some machines and absent on others.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's what your `catch` clause is for, to handle exceptions. It doesn't have to rethrow them:

```
tuple<string, int> Utility::RunCommand(const string& arguments) const
{
    string response;
    int exitCode;
    try
    {
        ipstream iStream;
        auto childProcess = child(arguments, std_out > iStream);
        string line;

        while (getline(iStream, line) && !line.empty())
        {
            response += line;
        }

        childProcess.wait();
        exitCode = childProcess.exit_code();
    }
    catch (PlatformNotSupportedException& e)
    {
        std::cerr << "That operation is not supported on this platform." << std::endl;
        exit(1);
    }
    catch (...)
    {
        std::cerr << "Unspecified error occurred." << std::endl;
        exit(1); // give nonzero exit code
        //throw; // take out this
    }

    return make_tuple(response, exitCode);
}
```

Comment: I can do that. But is there a way to avoid going into the catch? Basically a way to execute the command such that it returns from the method. Also, does exit(1) exit from the application? I would like to return back to the caller.

Comment: @commandocaddy So wait, do you want the exception to be thrown and caught in this method, which then returns? Or do you want no exception at all?

Comment: Ideally no exception at all. Because a huge number of machines will not have this executable. I would want to prevent exception handling as it could be expensive.

Comment: @commandocaddy Then why not modify your method to not throw an exception, and instead just emit the corresponding exit code? Then you won't need exception handling.